# array manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a two column array (array1), for each row of that array I need to compare the value in the 2nd column with a column value in each row of another array(array1) , when they equal I want to append another column value (from array2) to the first array.

in english:

```
if array1[x][1] = array2[y][0]
then array1[x][2] = array2[y][2]
```

screen dumps of both arrays

```
array1 ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 [1] => 2 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 2 [1] => 3 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 [1] => 
    ) [7] => Array ( 
        [0] => 7 [1] => 1 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [0] => 8 [1] => 1 
    ) 
    [9] => Array (
        [0] => 9 [1] => 10 
    ) 
    [10] => Array (
        [0] => 10 [1] => 2 
    ) 
)


array2 ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 2 
        [3] => Jane 
        [4] => Smith 
        [5] => jsmith@internet.com 
        [6] => jsmith 
        [7] => 12345 
        [8] => 1 
        [9] => no 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 2 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 3 
        [3] => James 
        [4] => Beard 
        [5] => jasb@bellsouth.net 
        [6] => jbeard03 
        [7] => keeper 
        [8] => 1 
        [9] => no 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 
        [3] => Peter 
        [4] => Allen 
        [5] => pallen@rfgg.com 
        [6] => pallen 
        [7] => pallen 
        [8] => 1 
        [9] => no 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => 7 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 1 
        [3] => Joe 
        [4] => Blow 
        [5] => jasb@bellsouth.net 
        [6] => jblow 
        [7] => blow123 
        [8] => 5 
        [9] => yes 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [0] => 8 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 1 
        [3] => John 
        [4] => Smith 
        [5] => logtest@bellsouth.net 
        [6] => jnsmith 
        [7] => jsmith123 
        [8] => 4 
        [9] => yes 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [0] => 9 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 10 
        [3] => Frank 
        [4] => Smith 
        [5] => pallen@test.com 
        [6] => fsmith 
        [7] => fsmith123 
        [8] => 4 
        [9] => yes 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [0] => 10 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 2 
        [3] => Loretta 
        [4] => Beard 
        [5] => lbeard@me.net 
        [6] => lbeard 
        [7] => lbeard123 
        [8] => 1 
        [9] => no 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, format this please. There's a preview pane and formatting help on the submission/edit page.

Comment: aspunishmentweshallwriteouranswersusingnopunctuationorspaces ;-P

Comment: @Tomalak - You can ask that the code be formatted without resorting to cursing. :)

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to submit, I went to look up formatting rules, when I came back you had already fixed it - a thousand pardons

Comment: I have been trying that - seemed easy, but I just can't seem to figure out the correct logic

Comment: actually I tried foreach because the values in the first column of array1 are not sequential - my problem seems to be that I am not checking each row in array1

Comment: That works too they will achieve the same result

Comment: any sample code I can try? - I will go back and find my best effort and post it for review if that will help (I figured my code didn't work and would just clutter the page more than my unformatted original post

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array1 as &$a1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $a2) {
        if ($a1[1] == $a2[0]) {
            $a1[] = $a2[2];
            continue 2;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you should try to use explicit keys that actually mean something, e.g. `$a1['id']` instead of `$a1[1]`. You'll thank yourself when you look at the code again two months down the road.

And because I threatened to do so:

btwyoushouldtrytouseexplicitkeysthatactuallymeansomethingeg$a1['id']insteadof$a1[1]youllthankyourselfwhenyoulookatthecodeagaintwomonthsdowntheroad ;-P

Comment: you are a gentleman and a scholar, that was it - thank you very much

Comment: @James I *do* in fact happen to have the Scholar badge, but I don't think there's a Gentleman badge.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I'm not sure I'm entirely clear on what you're looking for.

```
foreach($array1 as $x => $xarray) {
    foreach($array2 as $y => $yarray) {
        if($xarray[1] == $yarray[0]) {
            $array1[$x][2] = $array[$y][2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I was going strictly by your "in English" pseudo code, but I think you'd probably just want $array1[$x][] = $array[$y][2]; for the fourth line so that every match is appended. Otherwise if there were more than one match, $array1[x][2] would get overwritten by subsequent ones.

Comment: That's also why you should `continue 2` when you found a match; saves needless iterations and doesn't overwrite on subsequent matches.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't realize he wanted the first match only. In that case, your answer works anyway, so this is just doing it without doing it by reference.